# Is a JSpinner float input possible?how?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

Is it possible to have a JSpinner dealing with floats? I've got floats like 10E-20 so I can't use Doubles ,it has to be floats ... but there is no class SpinnerNumberModel that deals with floats ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't really understand why you can't use doubles, but ok.

`SpinnerNumberModel` is able to deal with floats, but you have to hand them is as `Float` objects. There is [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html#SpinnerNumberModel%28java.lang.Number,%20java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Comparable,%20java.lang.Number%29) constructor, which accepts `Number` and `Comparable` objects.

But remember that float isn't able to represent that small numbers. For such high precision you should use the `BigDecimal` class, which is also a subclass of `Number`.([Javadoc BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html))

Comment: Edit: added the BigDecimal part

Comment: ok I don't really understand why i can't use doubles either I've got something like this but I don't see why it doesn't work!

Comment: who tells you to only use floats?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how Java's `Number`, `Integer`, `Double`, `Float` work.

`java.lang.Number` is super type of `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Double` as well as `java.lang.Float`, ....

The `SpinnerNumberModel` class has the following constructor

```
public SpinnerNumberModel(Number value,
                  Comparable minimum,
                  Comparable maximum,
                  Number stepSize)
```

I see absolutely no reason why we cannot supply `Float` instead of `Number` since `Float` is subtype of `Number`. Float that is reference type, not float that is primitive.

```
Float value = new Float(50.28817271727);
Float step = new Float(5.29182);
SpinnerNumberModel model = new SpinnerNumberModel(value, null, null, step);
```